# When does topological homogeneity imply algebraic homogeneity? Pseudo-arc and Hilbert cube

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups, topological-algebras

Knaster's pseudo-arc and Hilbert cube are topologically homogeneous continua. The easier question is: do these spaces admit a topological group structure? (I am sure that the answer is negative). Thus the harder question is, do they admit a structure of a quotient of a topological group divided (left or right) by a closed (not necessarily normal) subgroup?

One could also ask extra about other non-obvious homogenous topological spaces, and also about other topological algebraic structures different from the two mentioned above, i.e. from a topological group or its quotient by a closed subgroup.

**Added**: I was always curious (but didn't do much about it), if the pseudo-arc can be supplied with an interesting geometric structure, even if it is made up ad hoc for the pseudo-arc.

Comment: Can you just take the group to be the group of self-homeomorphisms?

Comment: The HC indeed admits no group structure because every continuous self map has a fixed point (use Brouwer's fixed point theorem on $n$-dimensional projections, then pass to a limit on a subsequence), but of course $x\mapsto ax$ for $a\not= e$ doesn't.

Comment: @Will Sawin: That's a group structure on a different space.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: I'm thinking about the second question. Clearly we need to quotient by the stabilizer of a point.

Comment: @Christian: indeed! (I feel a bit embarrassed). Actually, both the Hilbert Cube and the pseudo-arc have the fixed point property, so that they cannot support a topological group. It's even hard to imagine a quotient G/H which would have the fixed point property (when it doesn't than again the mentioned two spaces cannot be interpreted as a G/H).

Comment: There are certainly quotients of compact groups that have the fixed point property (for instance, even-dimensional projective spaces).

Comment: The quotient $G/H$ has the fixed point property exactly when the conjugates of $H$ cover $G$.  This can't happen for finite groups (conjugate by $G/N_G(H)$ and count the elements) but can happen for infinite groups.  In Eric's example $G$ is a compact Lie group and $H$ is any subgroup containing a maximal torus.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the pseudoarc has the property that it admits no interesting binary operations at all: namely, every continuous map $X \times X \to X$ factors through the projection onto one of the coordinates.

Comment: Eric and Lior, thank you (I am doing worse and worse--so be it). And @Alexander, this would be interesting. However this still doesn't preclude an interesting geometric structure.

Comment: Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space.  Then $G=\mathrm{Homeo}(X)$ is a topological group in the compact-open topology, and the (algebraic) action of $G$ on $X$ is continuous.  It follows that point stabilizers $H$ are closed.  What is not obvious to me is that (in the transitive case) the quotient topology of $G/H$ is homeomorphic to $X$.  This is the

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it was mentioned in the comments, the pseudo-arc and the Hilbert cube have the fixed point property so they cannot be homeomorphic to a topological group.

On the other hand it was proved by G.S. Ungar in "*On all kinds of homogeneous spaces*" (TAMS, 1975), that any homogeneous compact metric space is homeomorphic to a coset space. In particular this is true for both the pseudo-arc and the Hilbert cube.

The fact that the pseudo-arc is a coset space was first proved by T.S. Wu in "*Each homogeneous nondegenerate chainable continuum is a coset space*" (PAMS, 1961).

I don´t know who proved first that the Hilbert cube is a coset space, but it also follows from a theorem of L.F. Ford in "*Homeomorphism groups and coset spaces*" (TAMS, 1954), namely that any homogeneous strongly locally homogeneous Tychonoff space is a coset space.